# Generate gallery loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

**The Problem**

I'm attempting to generate a gallery where it will display 3 "blocks" per row and alternate between large and small images.

For example:

```
Big     |   4 Small     |   Big

4 Small |   Big         |   4 Small
```

One big image is the size of 4 small images.

**What I've Tried**

Here's an example of what I've tried so far.

```
            $i = 0;
            $r = 0;
            $image = '';
            foreach($gallery_images as $image_data) {

                ($i == 5 ? $i = 0 : '');

                //If there's been 3 blocks added to the row, end the row and start a new one
                if($r == 3) { $image .= '</div>'; $r = 0; }

                //Start new row every 3 blocks
                if($r == 0) { $image .= '<div class="row">'; }

                //One big image, per 4 small in sequence
                if($i == 0) {
                    $image .= '<div style="height: 300px; width:33.3%; background: red;float:left;"></div>';
                    ++$r;
                } else {
                    //If no small, start the block
                    if($i == 1) { $image .= '<div style="width:33.3%;height:300px;float:left;">'; }
                        //echo each small image
                        $image .= '<div style="height: 150px; width:50%;background: blue;float:left;"></div>';

                    //Once 4 images have been echoed, close the div
                    if($i == 4) { $image .= '</div>'; ++$r; }
                }

                ++$i;

            }
            echo $image;
```

The first row displays fine, but then the next row messes up completely. I just can't see what I've missed in order for this to work.

The class of "row" is because I'm building this upon the foundation framework by Zurb in order to make it responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that on the 2nd row(s), you do not increment `$r` to `1` until the end of the 4 small, so it continues to add `<div class="row">` before each small image. You need to change your `if` block on the even rows. You can do this by adding 1 more counter, that keeps track of what row you are on -

by adding

```
$t=0;
```

and changing

```
//Start new row every 3 blocks
if($r == 0) { $image .= '<div class="row">'; }
```

to

```
//Start new row every 3 blocks
if($t%2==1){ // if we are on an even row
    if($i == 1 && $r == 0) { $image .= '<div class="row">';}
}
else{ // if we are on an odd row
    if($r == 0) { $image .= '<div class="row">'; }
}
```

you now have-

```
$i = 0;
$r = 0;
$image = '';
$t=0; // counter for odd/even row
foreach($gallery_images as $image_data) {

         ($i == 5 ? $i = 0 : '');
            //If there's been 3 blocks added to the row, end the row and start a new one
            if($r == 3) { $image .= '</div>'; $r = 0; ++$t; }

          //Start new row every 3 blocks
          if($t%2==1){ // if we are on an even row
              if($i == 1 && $r == 0) { $image .= '<div class="row">';} // if it is the first small image group start the row
          }
          else{ // if we are on an odd row
                 if($r == 0) { $image .= '<div class="row">'; }  // if it is the first large image
          }

            //One big image, per 4 small in sequence
            if($i == 0) {
                $image .= '<div style="height: 300px; width:33.3%; background: red;float:left;"></div>';
                ++$r;
            } else {
                //If no small, start the block
                if($i == 1) { $image .= '<div style="width:33.3%;height:300px;float:left;">'; }
                    //echo each small image
                    $image .= '<div style="height: 150px; width:50%;background: blue;float:left;"></div>';

                //Once 4 images have been echoed, close the div
                if($i == 4) { $image .= '</div>'; ++$r; }
            }

            ++$i;

        }
        echo $image;
```

you can see a phpFiddle example at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/t25-kbe This is with 60 images, so there is 4 rows total, 2 of each pattern.

Comment: tested the phpFiddle after I posted and realized that `if($t%2==1){if($i == 1){...}}` needed to be `if($t%2==1){if($i == 1 && $r == 0){...}}`, so that it checks both the `$i` and the `$r`. I have updated both my answer and the phpFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

NEW ANSWER:

Ok this is how you wanted it:

```
<style type="text/css">
.big {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#03F;    
}
.small {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#F00;    
}
</style>

<?

$gallery_images = array(
 1,2,3,4,5,6
);          
        echo '<div class="row">';
        //count counts whether it's big or small
        $count = 0;
        //count2 counts whether it's the end of the row or not
        $count2 = 0; 
        $row   = 0;
        foreach($gallery_images as $image_data) {
            //assign these from image data
            $big = "<img class='big'>"; 
            $small =  array(
                "<img class='small'>","<img class='small'>","<img class='small'>","<img class='small'>"
            );
            //if it's 0 it's big else it's 1 and it's small 
            if($count === 0) {
                echo $big;
                $count++; 
            }else {
                foreach($small as $s) {
                    echo $s;    
                }; 
                $count = 0; 
            }
                            //if it's 2 then its the end of the row else increment
            if($count2 === 2) {
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row'>";   
                $count2 = 0;
            }else {
                $count2 ++;
            }   


        }


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

NEW:

Ok you'd need to tinker with this, but I think it solves the issue:

```
<style type="text/css">
.big {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#03F;    
}
.small {
width:50px;
height:50px;
    background:#F00;    
}
</style>

<?
        $gallery_images = array(
         1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
        );           
        //find out how many images
        $total_images = count($gallery_images); 

        echo '<div class="row">';
        //count counts whether it's big or small
        $count = 0;
        //count2 counts whether it's the end of the row or not
        $count2 = 0; 
        $row   = 0;
        //overall count of images 
        $overall = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($gallery_images);$i++) {
            //assign these from image data
            $big = "<img class='big' src='".$gallery_images[$i]."'>"; 
            //increment overall
            $overall++;
            if($i+1 < $total_images) {
                $small1 = $i+1;
                $small[] = $small1; //would be $gallery_images[$small1]
                $overall++;
            }
            if($i+1 < $total_images) {
                $small2 = $i+2;
                $small[] = $small2;  //would be $gallery_images[$small2]
                $overall++;
            }
            if($i+1 < $total_images) {
                $small3 = $i+3;
                $small[] = $small3; //would be $gallery_images[$small3]
                $overall++;
            }
            if($i+1 < $total_images) {
                $small4 = $i+4;
                $small[] = $small4; //would be $gallery_images[$small4]
                $overall++;
            }
            //if it's 0 it's big else it's 1 and it's small 
            if($count === 0) {
                if($overall < $total_images) {
                    echo $big;
                    $count++; 
                }
            }else {
                if($small) {
                    foreach($small as $s) {
                        echo "<img class='small' src='".$s."' />";
                    }; 
                    $count = 0; 
                }
            }
            if($count2 === 2) {
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='row'>";   
                $count2 = 0;
            }else {
                $count2 ++;
            }   
            unset($small);
            if($overall >= $total_images) {
                echo "</div>";  
            }
        }


?>
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks fine but the functionality isn't there. In $gallery_images, there's one 16 images. But the foreach echo's a lot more, simply because foreach it will echo 4 small images, when it shouldn't, it should just use 4 images out of the 16 available. If that makes sense?